# url validator and shortener in python

Tags: python, url, validation

i wrote an easy url validator and shortener in python, how can i save  an image in small size from the website url? and recognise that it is not a "file" like .rar or .zip? i apreciate if you edit my code to have a better performance..

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
from urlparse import urlparse
import string
import random

url = raw_input('plZ enter the url: ').lower()      #get input and convert to lowercase
while True:
    if url[0:7] == 'http://' or url[0:8] == 'https://' or url[0:6] =='ftp://':          #check the url protocol
        try:                                        #try to open url
            response = urlopen(url)
            parsed_url = urlparse(url)
            rand_url = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_lowercase) for x in range(6))
            print " The shortened url is: http://url.com/" + rand_url
            print "\n Original URL is: "+url
            exit()
        except URLError, e:                         #except the error by asking the address again
            if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
                print "URL is not valid or server is NOT responsive..plZ try again.."
                url = raw_input('plZ enter the url: ').lower()
            #print 'Reason: ', e.reason
            elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
                print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'       #message in case of server or connection error
                print 'Error code: ', e.code
    else:
        print "\n protocol missing, using HTTP instead.. \n"
        url = "http://"+url
```

Comment: Do you think about favicon or rather of image of whole page as it is shown by Opera, Firefox or Chrome they shows in "Quick dial"?

Comment: exactly the image like opera and firefox..

Comment: Don't use `lower()`. Urls are case-sensitive, in principle and often in practice.

Comment: i did this to write less code to check the protocol, by lower() now i just check http, not HTTP or Http or hTTp,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you are looking to grab and image and resize it, Consider using either PIL or PyImageMagik [Python bindings for the excellent ImageMagik]

2) If you are looking to grab the screenshot of the page, then many people have the asked the same before. You can always use the solutions mentioned in point 1) above after grabbing the screenshot to resize. Webkit2png is good tool to realize the same.

http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/